# Is it possible to outsource the dependencyManagement to a file (have a local BOM)?

Tags: java, maven

I know that I can import dependencyManagement entries to a POM by using a so-called BOM from the repository. I wonder if there is a similar mechanism to reference a file *in the same project*.

We are generating POMs in an automated conversion step from Ant to Maven. For reproducibility, we need to generate quite a long dependencyManagement section. I would to be nice to put it into a separate file in the same project.

Is this possible?

Comment: It’s a pity that `<systemPath />` does not work for this case.

Comment: @MichaelPiefel The system scope is something that will be very probably be removed some time in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is explicitly not supported with Maven 2 and 3. It was asked in [MNG-3556](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-3556), but was closed as "Won't Fix". The reason is that it would allow the creation of POMs that are no longer self-contained. What you can do here, is make a concrete Maven project containing the BOM you're generating, release it, and then import it in other projects with `<scope>import</scope>`.

But, it migth be done in the future with version 5.0.0 of the POM model. Ideas about it are written [on this Confluence page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=65875544) and it does contain the notion of mixins, asked in [MNG-5102](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5102), which would allow parts of the POM to be included from other sources.